# memcpy writing to an object of type ‘class uint256’

Tags: c++, memory-management, memcpy

Well, this is probably a really simple warning to fix, but I didn't figure it out yet. Some time ago, I made an update for my `uint256` class, and after that, I get this warning:

```
base58.h:261:52: warning: ‘void* memcpy(void*, const void*, size_t)’ writing to an object of type ‘class uint256’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use copy-assignment or copy-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
         memcpy(&id, &vchData[0], HASH_LEN_BYTES);
```

This is the function where is the memcpy:

```
bool GetKeyID(CKeyID &keyID) const {
    if (!IsValid())
        return false;
    switch (nVersion) {
    case PUBKEY_ADDRESS:
    case PUBKEY_ADDRESS_TEST: {
        uint256 id;
        memcpy(&id, &vchData[0], HASH_LEN_BYTES);
        keyID = CKeyID(id);
        return true;
    }
    default: return false;
    }
}
```

This is my uint256 class: [uint256.h](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/397668ea63e148a92f68e9fae578595585616770/src/uint256.h)

Comment: Did the error start occurring after you added the completely unnecessary copy construction and assignment?

Comment: why are you using memcpy? what's wrong to use simply the copy constructor?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, my previous code was this: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.8.6/src/uint256.h . But i was needing add a feature and i decide to do a full update

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi please provide an code example so i can understead you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a copy-assignment for `base_uint<N>` class [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/397668ea63e148a92f68e9fae578595585616770/src/uint256.h#L50)

And a copy constructor for `base_uint` [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/397668ea63e148a92f68e9fae578595585616770/src/uint256.h#L44), and a conversion constructor `uint256` [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/397668ea63e148a92f68e9fae578595585616770/src/uint256.h#L479)

Also if you simply cast your `(uint256*)` argument to `(void*)` the warning will disapear, and you will have the expected behavior, but that's not the recommended way to do, because it may break silently in the future if you really make something different in the assignment. I think the best is to remove those copy constructors, and assignment operator. The only operator that would be interesting in my view is a conversion between `base_uint` of different widths.

Comment: Your answere help me a lot, Thanks man! a small correction if someone have this same problem: you dont want delete conversion constructor uint256, you need it on the get/set arround line 550. Then, deleteing base_uint<N> and base_uint and all is good!

Answer (score 1):

There are two alternative solutions:

- Make the class trivially copyable.
- Do not attempt to memcpy the class.

> how i can replace memcpy on this context?

Write a constructor accepting whatever `vchData` is as an argument.

> how i can make the class trivially copyable?

Remove copy constructor and any members / bases that are not trivially copyable.

Comment: how i can replace memcpy on this context? | how i can make the class trivially copyable? Please, provide some code-solution and i accept your answere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ValentinoZaffrani Get rid of the copy constructors and assignment operator - you should only implement those when they're needed. You're only duplicating what the compiler does better.

Comment: Or stuff the vchData into a vector<unsigned char> and use the existing constructor for that.

Comment: @eerorika ok, im going to do that, when i finish if all works good i approve your answere. Thanks!